# Any idea what this audio cable is for? It doesn't seem to be a mic or a light... totally flustered

Tags: audio

Any idea what this audio cable is for?  It doesn't seem to be a mic or a light... totally flustered.

[image: audio cable end closeup]
[audio cable image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yptr.jpg)

Comment: R U sure its an audio cable. Kinda looks like a temperature probe to me.

Comment: That looks like an **infrared transmitter or receiver** to me. You should really add why you think it's for audio. Are you just saying that because of the 3.5mm jack? Those are used for many things. I have a soldering iron that is powered via a 3.5mm plug.

Comment: Connectors can be used for anything the designers wish. Just because something is commonly used for one task, don't assume it always is.

Comment: If it's an audio cable then, I guess, it's for..... audio?

Comment: Thank you for all your input. And yes, I did jump to the "audio" conclusion. The IR remote clue triggered the answer... I tested it plugged into my TV channel receiver... it extends the reach of the remote signal. Mystery solved... thank you all again!

Comment: Thanks, Emerson. I don't think you've grasped that this isn't a forum - it's a Q&A site where answers float up and down with votes ond user sorting preference and since this isn't an answer it will probably be deleted. You can give thanks to useful answers by voting up and accept the best answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 5):

It looks very similar to the one in a picture from a well known supplier:

[image]

*Figure 1. IR pickup.*

- Place of Origin: Guangdong, China (Mainland)
- Brand Name: SLR
- Model Number: slr-ir1
- Type: Optical Fiber (dubious)
- Application: DVD Player
- Testing: 100% open & short test
- Working Temperature: -25oC ~ +85oC
- IR emitter: 36 kHz - 38 kHz, 20 - 60 kHz

Internally it would be just something like this:

[image]

*Figure 2. VR838 IR receiver.*

Its purpose is probably to pickup an IR remote control signal without direct line of sight to the box being controlled. e.g. A DVD player in a cabinet could have the IR sensor discretely placed outside the cabinet.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like IR receiver to me.   This kind of jack connector can be used for any applications not just for audio.